# Loop to get data from a table results in NaN allocated inside array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I'm trying to get the input(which are numbers) from a dynamic table, specifically the bottom part, the "demanda" row. [Here you can get a visual representation of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5pTy.png).

And for that I came up with the code below me, in it z=0 and x=1 before entering the loop and the length of the array b[] is the value of m (this goes tied in with the dynamic table). The problem is that this results in a NaN (which is not desired) when I see the values from a console.log  that I don't know where it comes from.

Here is the full Js code:

```
var inicio = function () {
    var getDatos = function () {
        var rows = parseInt($("#rows").val());
        var cols = parseInt($("#cols").val());
        rows = rows + 1;
        cols = cols + 1;
        var r1 = 1;
        var numero = 1;
        var num = 1;
        var renglones = "<table class='centered bordered'><thead><tr><th data-field='no'></th>";
        while (rows >= r1) {
            var c1 = cols;
            var c2 = cols + 2;
            if (r1 == 1) {
                var letra = 65;
                var valor = 2;
                while (c1 > 0) {
                    if (c1 == 1) {
                        renglones = renglones.concat("<th data-field=titulo'" + valor + "'>Oferta</th>");
                        c1--;
                    }
                    else {
                        renglones = renglones.concat("<th data-field=titulo'" + valor + "'>" + String.fromCharCode(letra) + "</th>");
                        letra++;
                        valor++;
                        c1--;
                    }
                }
                renglones = renglones.concat("</tr></thead><tbody>");
            }
            renglones = renglones.concat("<tr>");
            while (c2 > 0) {

                if (c2 == (cols + 2)) {

                    if (r1 == rows) {
                        renglones = renglones.concat("<td>Demanda</td>");
                        c2--;
                    }
                    else {
                        renglones = renglones.concat("<td>" + num + "</td>");
                        num++;
                        c2--;
                    }

                }
                else if (c2 == 1) {
                    renglones = renglones.concat("</tr>");
                    c2--;
                }

                else if (c2 == 2 && r1 == rows) {
                    renglones = renglones.concat("<td></td>");
                    c2--;
                }

                else {
                    renglones = renglones.concat("<td><input  id='caja" + numero + "' type='number' class='validate'></td>");
                    c2--;
                    numero++;
                }

            }
            if (r1 == rows) {
                renglones = renglones.concat("</tbody> </table>");

            }

            r1++;
        }
        renglones = renglones.concat("<div class='row'><div class='col s12 center'><a class='waves-effect waves-light btn ' id='btnAceptar'>Aceptar</a></div></div>");

        $("#divTabla").html(renglones);
        $("#divTabla #btnAceptar").on("click", metodoEsn);
    };

    var metodoEsn = function () {
        var m = parseInt($("#rows").val());//renglones
        var n = parseInt($("#cols").val());//columnas
        var tp = new Array(m + 1);
        var allo = new Array(m + 1);
        var x = 1;
        var z = 0;
        var a = new Array(m + 1);//5
        var b = new Array(n + 1);
        //int tp[][]= new int[5][5];
        var k = 1, count = 0;
        var tc = 0, mult = 1, sum = 0;
        var i, j;
        var c_sum = 0, d_sum = 0;

        for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            //se crean las columnas de la tabla
            tp[i] = new Array(n + 1);
            console.log("se creo la columna numero " + i);
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            allo[i] = new Array(n + 1);
            console.log("se creo la columna numero " + i + "de allo");
        }

        //Se ingresan los valores de la tabla
        for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {

                tp[i][j] = parseInt($("#caja" + x).val());
                allo[i][j] = 0;
                console.log("se ingresa el valor de la caja " + i + " " + j);
                x++;
            }
        }
        x = 0;

        //Ingresa Oferta
        for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            x += n + 1;
            a[i] = parseInt($("#caja" + x).val());
            c_sum += a[i];
            console.log("se ingresa la caja" + a[i]);
        }

        x = 1;
        console.log("valor " + c_sum);
        //Ingresa Demanda
        console.log("se ingresa la demanda");

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            x += m + 2;
            z++;
            if (z == m) {
                for (k = 1; k < n + 2; k++) {
                    x++;
                    b[k] = parseInt($("#caja" + x).val());
                    d_sum += b[k];
                    console.log("se ingresa el valor de la caja " + k);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log("valor " + d_sum);

        for (i = 1; i <= b.length; i++) {
            console.log(b[i]);
        }

        console.log("se inician las cuentas de esn");

        if (c_sum == d_sum) {
            for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
                console.log("todo bien");
                for (j = k; j <= n; j++) {
                    console.log("todo bien x2");
                    if (a[i] > b[j]) {
                        console.log("todo bien x3");
                        mult = tp[i][j];
                        mult = mult * b[j];
                        allo[i][j] = b[j];
                        a[i] = a[i] - b[j];
                        sum += mult;
                        mult = 1;
                        count++;
                        console.log("por aqui todo bien");
                        //k=1;

                    } else {
                        mult = tp[i][j];
                        mult *= a[i];
                        allo[i][j] = a[i];
                        b[j] = b[j] - a[i];
                        sum += mult;
                        mult = 1;
                        k = j;
                        count++;
                        console.log("por aqui tambien");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log("se termino de hacer el metodo");

            var tabla = "<table class='centered bordered'>";
            tabla = tabla.concat("<table> <tbody>");
            for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
                tabla = tabla.concat("<tr>");
                for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                    tabla = tabla.concat("<td>" + allo[j][i] + "</td>");

                }
                tabla = tabla.concat("</tr>");
            }
            tabla = tabla.concat("</tbody> </table>");

            $("#divTabla2").html(tabla);
            console.log("se despliega la tabla");

            if ((m + n - 1) == count)
                console.log("Z es igual a: " + sum);
            else {
                console.log("La solucion de este problema no se puede encontrar");
            }


        }

    };

    $("#btnCrear").on("click", getDatos);
```

HTML code posted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css"        media="screen,projection"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Problemas de transporte: Metodo Esquina Superior Noroeste.</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h5>Problemas de transporte: Metodo Esquina Superior Noroeste.</h5>
    ESN?
    <P>Primero que nada, que es el metodo de ESN?<br> El método de la esquina Noroeste es un algoritmo heurístico capaz de solucionar problemas de transporte o distribución mediante la consecución de una solución básica inicial que satisfaga todas las restricciones existentes sin que esto implique que se alcance el costo óptimo total. </p>
        <br>

        <h6>Calcular</h6>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="rows" type="number" class="validate">
            <label for="rows">Origenes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input id="cols" type="number" class="validate">
            <label for="cols">Destinos</label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 center"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn " id="btnCrear">Crear</a></div>
        </div>

</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div id="divTabla"></div>
<div id="divTabla2"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the use of `break;` here

Comment: Please post your html code

Comment: ill add it right now.

Comment: i thought of using break to skip the outer loop once finished getting the data into the array.

Comment: Most obvious place for an NaN related error is  `b[k]=parseInt($("#caja"+x).val());` the initial value of x is unknown in the snippet provided. also `#caja...` isn't present in the snippet probably due to the dynamic nature of the table as you mentioned. Chances are the `.val())` call is not returning an integer. Beyond that we need a more complete code example to provide further guidance such as a simple fiddle demonstrating the issue or at the very least sufficient code that we can reproduce and hence debug the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the value of n.

Comment: `break` how it's currently used will exit the outer loop after the first iteration it will likely cause undesired results as if you only need one iteration you probably don't need the loop. So either the break is superfluous, the loop is, or there's an issue with the logic.

Comment: I added the full js code to get more context of what comes from where.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue no errors only debug messages logged to console reporting a NaN if I leave a field blank or enter a letter in a field (such as Demanda A = e) I've put together a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k04jc0de/ seems to work i think. In Chrome at least I don't know what the form is supposed to do differently. If you can please cut the fiddle down so that it provides an MCVE (stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and give a bit more detail on how to reproduce the issue and what it should be doing that it's not that would be a big help. Cheers, Brian.

Comment: the issue is that i need the values from the inputs which are expected to be numbers thats why i used a lot of console.logs xD to know what was going on, and then i realised i got NaN

Comment: also i think i made a mistake, it doesnt come out as an error, its more of a discrepancy from what im trying to get and what im getting. im going to edit that in thi question.

Comment: All good - if it's the "valor NaN" being logged that's the issue I still think my first comment prob is the best bet - `parseInt` was the only possible cause at least in the partial snippet that you initially provided - cause is empty fields or letters being passed into `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I fixed it, the code still gets an error of 'Uncaught type error:Cannot read property of undefined 1' at the line 227 but I'm going to figure out that myself; if someone is interested, I changed the 'for' loop for a 'while', like this:

```
//Ingresa Demanda
            console.log("se ingresa la demanda");
            var tope=(1+n)*(1+m);
            tope=tope-1;
            while(x!=tope){
                x++
                if(x>=tope-(n-1)){
                z++;
                b[z]=parseInt($("#caja"+x).val());
                d_sum+=b[z];
                }
            }
            console.log("valor"+d_sum);
```

Seems like the problem was the loop as someone said, so I tried changing it.